# Simplifying a product over roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $\zeta_{n}=e^{2\pi i /n}$ be the nth root of unity. Now consider the product :
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\zeta_{n}^{k})^{\zeta_{n}^{k}}$$
Is there a simple formula for this product as a function of $n$ !?

Comment: Note that $z^w$ is a multiple-valued function. Should we take the branch where $z$ doesn't lie on the negative real line?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't take your meaning !

Comment: Well, how do you define $(1-\zeta_n^k)^{\zeta_n^k}$?

Comment: ah.. ok ... yes, your $z$ doesn't lie on the negative real line .